# How to remove invalid characters in file path Using java?

Tags: java

I need to upload files and files this been written that way.
How can I replace in String?

Name File "Langelinie_All�_by_SirPecanGum.jpg"

I would just letters and numbers underscore filenames, as do using Regex

I try

```
String foo = "this is a thing with & in it";
foo = foo.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9()\\[\\]]", "");
```

dones't work

Comment: can you at least list your invalid characters ?

Comment: What are the allowed and disallowed characters in this case?

Comment: Define "dones't work". `foo = foo.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9()\\[\\]]", "");` returns `thisisathingwithinit` which seems to be correct result. What result you expect?

Comment: **"put on hold as off-topic by"** ?? there's nothing off topic here. voted to reopen.

Comment: @PedroLobito The off-topic part is that OP hasn't explained what he means by "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would just letters and numbers underscore as filenames

```
String foo = "Langelinie_All�_by_SirPecanGum.jpg";
foo = foo.replaceAll("[^\\w\\.]", "");
//Langelinie_All_by_SirPecanGum.jpg
```

I guess you also need the dot (`.`), otherwise it will cut the extension.

---

**DEMO**

http://ideone.com/zTFJF6

Comment: If the OP uses `Langelinie_All�_by_SirPecanGum.jpg`, it will remove the `.` of the extension, soo close :P

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out.